# Open every row of Gridview in edit mode

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Quick general question, is it possible to open every row of a Gridview in Edit mode, sort of like and Excel spreadsheet? Or is there maybe some other control that can do this?

I have played around a little and have not been able to do this. .net 3.5

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GridView TemplateFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) & add TextBox Controls to it.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Territories">
   <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server"/>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I do not thing that the idea is to just show a text box, but to actually saves the data on all together.

Comment: Saving data altogether or individually. The primary objective was to prevent clicking Edit and Update on every record to enter changes for each row. Even a free form type entry per row, like a spreadsheet is the vision.